# Extract row of same ids from from a list

Tags: r

I have a data frame containing id and other variables, and also a list which has some ids. Now I want to extract row of ids from the data frame which has same ids in list.

data frame

```
id   value  time
1     12     1.0
1     14     1.6
4     18     2.0
6     9      3.6
3     11     4.2
5     12     0.8
```

list

```
1,3,4
```

Result

```
id   value  time
1     12     1.0
1     14     1.6
3     11     4.2
4     18     2.0
```

Comment: Use `%in%`... We need to see the structure of your list to be able to help further. In general, please make sure your examples are [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sotos explained, that could be done as following using `%in%`:

```
Data[Data$id %in% list,]
# id value time
# 1:  1    12  1.0
# 2:  1    14  1.6
# 3:  4    18  2.0
# 4:  3    11  4.2
```

Comment: do you use `data.table`. The format looks not as a base `data.frame`?

Comment: FYI, I rejected your edit at the question as you are making an assumption that the list mentioned by OP is not a list but a vector. This can clearly conflict with OPs real object. This is also the reason that I did not dupe this question. Waiting for clarification

Comment: Hello @sotos. I agree with you. Given how he wrote it, assumed it was a vector given that otherwise he would have copied as he did with the table the result of R as [[1]] 1 [[2]] 3 etc. And given the accepted answer, I assumed that was the way. Nevertheless, i totally understand your point and probably it would have been better to ask him/her.